# IIncrementalGenerator - Get namespace of property type

Tags: c#, csharp-source-generator

Based on my property list I want to generated new code. For that I need to add the corresponding usings too.

How can I get the namespace of my property type?
In this case prop.Type.ToString()

```
private static void Execute(Compilation item1, ImmutableArray<(ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration, AttributeData attribute)> classes, SourceProductionContext context)
{
    foreach (var (classDeclaration, attribute) in classes)
    {
         var properties = classDeclaration.Members.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.IsKind(SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration));
         var props = properties.Select(o => o.ChildTokens().Single(n => n.IsKind(SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken)).ValueText).ToArray();

         var snapshotProperties = new List<SnapshotProperty>();
         foreach (var property in properties)
         {
             var prop = (PropertyDeclarationSyntax)property;

             snapshotProperties.Add(new SnapshotProperty(
                 prop.ToString(),
                 prop.Type.ToString(),
                 prop.Identifier.ValueText,
                 prop.Identifier.ValueText.ToLower()));
         }
    }
}

private class SnapshotProperty
{
    public string FullProperty { get; }
    public string Type { get; }
    public string PropertyName { get; }
    public string ParameterName { get; }

    public SnapshotProperty(string fullProperty, string type, string propertyName, string parameterName)
    {
        FullProperty = fullProperty;
        Type = type;
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        ParameterName = parameterName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [GetTypeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.modelextensions.gettypeinfo?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.6.0) extension method on a SemanticModel and from here you can get

- The type's name with `.Type.Name`
- The containing namespace's name with `.Type.ContainingNamespace.Name` (you may have to go through the ContainingNamesapce's ContainingNamespace if you have several namespaces like `Namespace1.Namespace2`)
- The type's full name via `.Type.ToDisplayString()` (some of the types that are aliased will display with their alias instead, for example usage on `System.Int32` will display `int`, see the [SpecialType](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.itypesymbol.specialtype?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.6.0) property for more)

If you don't already have one in the code that calls `Execute`, you can get a SemanticModel with `item1` (your parameter of type `Compilation`) using [GetSemanticModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation.getsemanticmodel?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.6.0) : `item1.GetSemanticModel(classDeclaration.GetLocation().SourceTree)`.

Assuming you want the type's full name, your execute method would then look like the following :

```cs
private static void Execute(Compilation item1, ImmutableArray<(ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration, AttributeData attribute)> classes, SourceProductionContext context)
{
    foreach (var (classDeclaration, attribute) in classes)
    {
        var properties = classDeclaration.Members.AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.IsKind(SyntaxKind.PropertyDeclaration));
        var props = properties.Select(o => o.ChildTokens().Single(n => n.IsKind(SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken)).ValueText).ToArray();
        var semanticModel = item1.GetSemanticModel(classDeclaration.GetLocation().SourceTree);
        var snapshotProperties = new List<SnapshotProperty>();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var prop = (PropertyDeclarationSyntax)property;

            snapshotProperties.Add(new SnapshotProperty(
                prop.ToString(),
                semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(prop.Type).Type.ToDisplayString(),
                prop.Identifier.ValueText,
                prop.Identifier.ValueText.ToLower()));
        }
    }
}
```